# Can't find variable: React after implementing Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm using React Native to build an app. The app worked fine until I tried to implement Redux, since then, I get an error `Can't find variable: React`

It says the problem is in index.js:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <App />
</Provider>
```

But I can't figure out why.
I do have `React` imported in my `App.tsx` file.
I tried reinstalling the app, but got the same error.

This is index.js:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import store from './src/state/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log("Store changed!", store.getState());
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => {
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
});
```

I didn't modified `App.tsx` (which worked fine before) and I do import `React` there (I didn't included it here because it is pretty large, and as I said, worked before and didn't changed).

I followed a tutorial because I'm new to React and React Native in general, and never implemented Redux of course, and everything was fine in the tutorial of course, and I don't really see what's the problem here.

Comment: Please, put your code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) so it's easier for us to inspect the whole thing. Thanks.

Comment: @Luka Thanks, I will, would you please tell me exactly what's needed?

Comment: Maybe it's easier for you to check my [boilerplate for React Native with Redux](https://github.com/harmonikas996/BoilerplateRN) implementation so you can compare it to yours. I just realized it's hard to put RN to codesandbox because it's working only for Web version

Comment: did you try running `npm install` after that? sometimes when I install some dependency I get this error and it's fixed after running `npm install`

Comment: Agreed, have you tried running `npm i` to ensure all your dependencies are installed before starting/building your app again? Where is `React` not being found? Do you just need to `import React from 'react';` in your index file? What version of React & React-native are you using? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm not super familiar with React Native, aren't you just missing importing React in your index file? or is that not needed in react native now like react 17 removed the need for it

Comment: Thanks everybody! For your question, I didn't try to ```npm install``` I'm new to the JS eco system and totally forgot about that option. @azium Thanks, it is not needed to import React in index.js as far as I know. Eventually, @Luka link helped me fixing the issue, I thought I need to use Provider in index.js but it seems to be working when using it in App.tsx instead.